# UWP TextBox invokes external handwriting app instead of "write directly into text field"

Tags: c#, uwp, handwriting-recognition

I have created a UWP app and deployed it onto a Windows 11 Surface tablet computer.

On this tablet computer, I have actived the option "Write directly into text feld", and typing with the finger is enabled.

However, when I tap the textbox, the external handwriting recognition window is opened up:

[image]

What is expected was this:

[image]

(taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/text-handwriting-view))

My XAML code is this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
         <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="980" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1480" FontSize="48" IsHandwritingViewEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What could I have forgotten?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your input device? is it pen device ?

Comment: I use my finger. That works.

Comment: it looks only available for pen device right ?

Comment: No, there is an option in Windows that says "Use finger as pen".

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Wow, thank you. It really only works when I use my pen. Even though I activated "Use finger as pen".

Answer (score 0):

It appears the page you referenced is about **disabling** what you are trying to get rid of. There is another page that describes the pen input you look to add; if I read correctly it uses MS Ink.

see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/text-handwriting-view

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
         <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="980" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1480" FontSize="48" IsHandwritingViewEnabled="False">
                 <TextBox.HandwritingView>
            <HandwritingView PlacementAlignment="TopLeft"/>
        </TextBox.HandwritingView>
         </TextBox>
         
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helpful, but the real reason was that for some reason, it only works with a pen (and not with a finger, even though this option is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

> UWP TextBox invokes external handwriting app instead of "write directly into text field" **I use my finger. That works.**

Derive from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/text-handwriting-view#overview) here, XAML text input boxes feature embedded support for **pen** input using Windows Ink. If you use touch, it will not show `HandwritingView`. please use pen device to replace, it will work well.